# how to design a Turing machine that could count Unary?

Tags: turing-machines, automata

am trying to figure out how to design a unary number Turing Machine. That after reading all the unary number in the tape it would give out a decimal value. how can i approach this problem?

Comment: I feel like I've seen this question before.  Ahh, yes, it is http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/72349/755.  If that was you, please don't delete your question and then re-post it -- especially when you re-post it without fully addressing the feedback you've gotten before.  For instance: What did you try? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.

Comment: Also, as previously requested/suggested: "explain what sort of machine you've got: are there working tapes, is the output tape separate from the input tape, what is the alphabet?" and "Do instructions specifically ask for a one-tape machine? If they do, you failed to mention it to us, so you're still not communicating."  I encourage you to [indicate the source of the problem](http://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing).  Where did you encounter this problem?  You previously mentioned the question is "Design a TM M that convert digits from unary representation to Decimal."

Comment: If the machine counts in unary, why does it give out a decimal value?

Comment: @D.W. what do u mean delete? i just posted the question.i don't know where to start, thats why i came here for help!

Comment: @DavidRicherby i just found the question while studying and couldn't figure out how to do that for all decimal numbers.

Comment: @user68918 A near-identical question was posted yesterday and then deleted.

Comment: @DavidRicherby, i guess as D.W. said but as it is deleted i cant access it.

Comment: The OP has trouble asking his questions, I think we should help him with that. After yesterday's conversations with him, I can tell what he is asking: *Construct a TM which takes as input a number in unary and outputs it in decimal.* Yesterday he wanted a one-tape machine, but perhaps today he'd be happy with a two-tape machine (separate input and outputs), as that would actually be far more useful than some hackery to get things working on a single tape. Also, the user is now hiding behind a different (anonymous?) username.

Comment: What have you tried, where did you get stuck? How do you make the conversion *on paper*?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Turing machine that should accomplish what you are looking for, I don't know how to teach someone how to make it, but I can explain how I made this. Note there is an error, the instruction from $S$ to $H$ of $(0,s,0)$ should be $(\lambda,s,0)$. Also I used $\lambda$ to represent the null character or the empty spot.

[image: Turing machine]

The starting state for the machine is $S$ and the halt state is $H$. First I said that if the tape is empty, then we simply write a $1$ and halt. If there is a $1$ then we will put a $*$ there and write a $1$ to the spot before, then we start our loop if you will.

The loop starts with the state $\text{go to end}$, from there we go to the end of the unary number. When know we got there when we see a $\lambda$ and then we know we've gone one to far. At this point we would move one left (to the last digit in the unary number) and to the state $\text{check if done}$, and here we have an end condition. If we currently see a $*$ then we have hit the end as there are no more unary numbers, and we move to the $\text{done}$, from where we move to the beginning of our decimal number and then halt.

If we don't see a $*$ then we would have to see a $1$ as it's a unary number. We delete that number and then go back to the beginning of the unary number (this is done in state $\text{go to start}$. From there we add 1 to the decimal number that is to the left of the $*$, This is done just using state $\text{add 1 from right}$, followed by $\text{go to *}$ which puts us back to the $*$ that separates the unary number from the decimal number. At this point we go to state 
$\text{go to end}$ again and the machine is already complete.

Here is the entire rules for the machine typed up with $S$ and $H$ as the start and halt state respectively. The rest of the states will be given letters arbitrarily. The form of the following is `(start state, value read, head movement, end state, value write)`. (head movement: `l` is left, `s` is stay, `r` is right). Also `\` will be our empty, and represents $\lambda$

```
(S,0,s,H,0)
(S,1,l,A,*)
(A,\,r,B,1)
(B,1,r,B,1)
(B,*,r,B,1)
(B,\,l,D,\)
(D,*,l,C,\)
(C,0,l,C,0)
(C,1,l,C,1)
(C,2,l,C,2)
(C,3,l,C,3)
(C,4,l,C,4)
(C,5,l,C,5)
(C,6,l,C,6)
(C,7,l,C,7)
(C,8,l,C,8)
(C,9,l,C,9)
(C,0,l,C,0)
(C,\,r,H,\)
(D,1,l,E,\)
(E,1,l,E,1)
(E,*,l,F,*)
(F,9,l,F,0)
(F,0,r,G,1)
(F,1,r,G,2)
(F,2,r,G,3)
(F,3,r,G,4)
(F,4,r,G,5)
(F,5,r,G,6)
(F,6,r,G,7)
(F,7,r,G,8)
(F,8,r,G,9)
(F,\,l,G,1)
(G,0,r,G,0)
(G,1,r,G,1)
(G,2,r,G,2)
(G,3,r,G,3)
(G,4,r,G,4)
(G,5,r,G,5)
(G,6,r,G,6)
(G,7,r,G,7)
(G,8,r,G,8)
(G,9,r,G,9)
(G,*,r,B,*)
```